# Will my B1/B2 visa allow me to enter the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

I am a citizen of India. My mom, my brother and I applied for tourist visas to visit the US. They gave us all B1/B2 M purpose visas. I am doing my masters at university, my brother is in college, and my mother is a government employee. Now we can't find holidays together so we can visit together. So I am planning to visit the US in January for one month, and my mom and brother will be going in June.

Some people I know are saying they won't let me in for sure. They will send me back. I dont know really what to do now. If I show them my documents, my returning ticket and everything, they still wouldn't let me enter? I don't have health insurance but I will be getting it soon for sure. I have some friends living in Texas and I want to visit them, but while applying for the visa I told them I will be going to New York. Will it be a problem that instead of going to New York I will be going to Texas?

Comment: these people you know who claim you won't be let in - did they give you some reason for believing the USA routinely issues visas to people and then doesn't let them in? That is a rather strange belief unless there is something those people know that you have not included in your question.

Comment: @KateGregory I suspect that the concern is that the actual travel plans won't be identical to those that were presented at the time of the visa application.  For a multiple entry visa, I doubt that will be any kind of problem.  Question for the OP: does "M" mean multiple entry?

Answer (score 7):

If you actually intend to visit the US and leave at the end of your visit, it's unlikely that you will have any trouble with US immigration. But to be sure:

The US visa allows you to travel to a port of entry in the United States and apply for admission. Your trip must be for one of the purposes allowed by the type of visa you received. For a B1/B2 visa, that includes tourism and business visits.

All you need to do is to show the immigration officer at the port of entry that you intend to visit for a purpose allowed by the visa, that you will leave the country at the end of your visit, and that you have enough money to support yourself for the duration of your visit and to return home.

This means:

**DO NOT bring every possible document with you.** Bring only documents that are relevant to demonstrating that you are visiting the US, that you have enough money, and that you intend to depart the US.

For example: hotel bookings and Disneyland tickets (which show you are a tourist), your bank statement and return tickets (which show you have enough money), a statement from your university showing that you are taking classes (which shows you intend to leave) and any other documents which demonstrate these points.

Do not bring your CV, diplomas, certifications, or anything else that might make the immigration officer think you are coming to work. Do not bring excessive amounts of clothing or personal effects, pets, or anything else that might make the immigration officer think you are coming to live in the US.

When asked how much money you have, answer *both* how much money you have on you, and how much available to spend in your bank account. (As an aside: The word "lakh" is not widely understood in the US; say "hundred thousand" instead.)

Read the questions on the landing card carefully and answer them truthfully. A "Yes" answer to a question does not necessarily make you inadmissible, but answering "No" when the correct answer is "Yes" virtually guarantees you will be refused entry. If you have criminal convictions, you should bring your records related to them (though if you had a criminal record which would make you inadmissible, you should have been refused a visa). Do not forget the food packed in your luggage; declare all food if you are carrying any. You need to tick Yes to the food question even if the food is allowed; you can be fined if you tick No and are carrying food, even if the food is allowed. But if you tick Yes and the food is not allowed, there is no penalty (other than having the food thrown out).

If you can do all of the above, you will most likely clear immigration and customs very quickly.